# How to set a timezone for all request based on one of the post parameter in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, datetime, express

I have a REST application built on Node.js Express and I want to scale it to other countries.
As all my date time related operations as of now are based on local timezone it is an issue if the request comes from a different timezone.

In each of my request can i have an identifier which defines that particular timezone and the server handles it accordingly.

For Eg :  if the country is USA ,so i would restrict each request to have a parameter say id and server identifies the timezone using that id.

Now challenge would be to change the server's timezone only for that particular request.

Comment: yes, that is a challenge. Almost as challenging as finding a question in your story

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that

> all your date time related operations as of now are based on local
>   timezone

Why don't you consider using an unified standard (UCT/GMT) for your server operations?

If for some reasons you need to persist local time value, you should also include the local time offset from UTC or store time in both formats.